# Get Last values using Select Substring in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with following Column

```
Name
----------------------
test10/20000020                     
test1/test2 / 20000001
test3/test4 / 20000002
test5/20000017
test5/test6 / 20000004
test5/20000007
```

I need to select the last value
I.e

```
20000020
20000001
20000002
20000017
20000004
20000007
```

I have tried with

```
(SUBSTRING(Name,0,(CHARINDEX('/',Name,0))))
```

But I am getting First Value
i.e.     test1
    test2
    test3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT SUBSTRING( Name, LEN(Name) -  CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(Name)) + 2  , LEN(Name) ) FROM SAMPLE

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Using XML:

```
declare @xml xml;
declare @str nvarchar(max) = '';
with data as
(
  select 'test1/test2/test3/344495' as r
  union ALL
  select 'test1/344556' as r
)
select @str = @str + '<r><v>' + replace(r,'/','</v><v>') + '</v></r>'
from data;
-- obtain xml
set @xml = cast(@str as xml);

-- select last value from each row
select v.value('(v/text())[last()]', 'nvarchar(50)')
from @xml.nodes('/r') as r(v)
```

Same idea but without variables:

```
;with data as
(
  select 'test1/test2/test3/344495' as r
  union ALL
  select 'test1/344556' as r
),
xmlRows AS
(
  select cast('<r><v>' + replace(r,'/','</v><v>') + '</v></r>' as xml) as r
  from data
)
select v.value('(v/text())[last()]', 'nvarchar(50)') as lastValue
from   xmlRows xr
       cross APPLY
       r.nodes('/r') as r(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

**SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )**

Instead of that

```
(SUBSTRING(Name,0,(CHARINDEX('/',Name,0))))
```

You should use

```
(SUBSTRING(Name,(CHARINDEX('/',Name,0)+1),8))
```

if string size is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem with the following query:

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING(Name,(CHARINDEX('/',Name,0)),LEN(Name)))
```